# How find long running and high RU queries in cosmos database

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a cosmos database for mongo api and I am trying to find the most expensive query and the highest RU consuming query in a database.

I can see the operation which is taking the high RU from metrics but I would also like to see the query which is taking the RU.

I do have diagnostic setting enabled and capturing DataPlaneRequests and MongoRequest. I have tried the below query but it doesn't provide any results

```
CDBMongoRequests
  | where todouble(RequestCharge) > 10.0
  | project ActivityId, RequestCharge
  | join kind= inner (
  CDBQueryRuntimeStatistics
  | project ActivityId, QueryText
  ) on $left.ActivityId == $right.ActivityId
  | order by RequestCharge desc
  | limit 100
```

Can someone help on how can I find the actual queries running?

Comment: Have you considered looking at the RU cost for each query manually via MongoDB command? You can do that via `db.runCommand('getLastRequestStatistics')`

Comment: `CDBQueryRuntimeStatistics` is for SQL API. You just need to be looking in `CDBMongoRequests` and not joining - use `PIICommandText` after enabling the option

Comment: Hi @DavidMakogon, thank you for the response. Can I use this to get the statistics of all queries executed in last week  or just the last request?

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith. I was able to execute the query after removing the join but the output received from the query doesn't match the output from metrics. The collection name for the most expensive query wrt RU is different.

Comment: Unclear what you are looking at in the metrics. The metrics is aggregate costs whereas the diagnostic logs are  individual costs